# "to reduce" or "to reducing"?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context, infinitives, to-infinitive

Grammarly indicates that something may be wrong writing just **to reduce**. However, when replaced by **to reducing** is marked completely wrong.

> By analyzing agricultural data and using software, I help this entity **to reduce** fuel consumption while keeping the number of passengers, thus reducing greenhouse gas’ emissions.

Comment: it's unclear from the context what "this entity" is, could you elaborate?

Comment: "help this entity to reduce" doesn't sound academic if that's the style this paragraph is supposed to be written in

Comment: "this entity" refers to a governmental's agricultural entity. It is stated in a paragraph previous to this one. Do you have suggestions to replace "help this entity to reduce" ?  I don't see clearly why it is not academic?. @AndrewTobilko

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`To reducing` is incorrect, *to* cannot be followed by gerund, unless *to* is a preposition that is part of a combination.

Examples can be found [here](http://www.englishteachermelanie.com/grammar-can-a-gerund-be-used-after-to/).

So in your example using `to reduce` is fine.